# Jquery:autocomplete values and categories.Error: this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here is the part of my Javascript:

```
$(function(){

var dbTags=<?php echo json_encode($namesArray);?>;
var myTag;

$("#searchTags").autocomplete({

  source: dbTags,
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui){

myTag=ui.item.value;
```

My php code:

```
$findNames=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT productTitle, category from Iranga ");
$findNames->execute();
$information=$findNames->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($information as $item){

   $namesArray=array("label:"=>$item['productTitle'], "category:"=>$item['category']);

}
```

Am planning to use this script:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

The question how to use and define my `dbTags` variable, when it contains product tilte and categories?

Answer (score 1):

If you're following the [example you linked](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) you want your "source" array to be an array of objects with "label" and "category" properties.  I'm not sure what your PHP output is, or what database api you're using (assuming PDO), but I would try:

```
$findNames=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT productTitle, category from Products");
$findNames->execute();
while ($row=$findNames->fetch()){
 $namesArray[] = array("label" => $row['productTitle'], "category" => $row['category']);
}
```

Comment: *"or what database api you're using"* - OP is using PDO.

Comment: what is `runQuery()`?

Comment: I'm not the OP btw ;-) But that must be some custom function.

Comment: Yes it is my custom function which is preparing sql query.

Comment: That code will work if your custom database is using PDO.  If it's not then you have to tell us what API it uses or figure out how to adjust my code yourself.  The error implies that the $row array(?) doesn't contain 'productTitle'.