# MySQL:Query with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im creating detailed product search.I verified that ,my variables are posted correctly, but the query don't finding anything. My question is:

What could be wrong in this query and what could be the best solution for detailed search in SQL?

```
<?php

if ( 
    isset($_POST["productName"]) || isset($_POST["searchCategory"]) || 
    isset($_POST["searchManufacturer"]) || isset($_POST["costFrom"]) || 
    isset($_POST["costTo"])
){

    $stmt=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT* FROM Products
        WHERE (productTitle='$_POST[productName]' OR '$_POST[productName]' IS NULL)
        AND   (category='$_POST[searchCategory]' OR '$_POST[searchCategory]' IS NULL)
        AND   (manufacturer='$_POST[searchManufacturer]' OR '$_POST[searchManufacturer]' IS NULL)

    ");
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump()` `$_POST`or `$stmt` or `errorInfo()` or what does `runQuery()` looks like?

Comment: I found, that the query is working only, when all parameters are posted.I need to redesign it, that the query could search the results  with 1 or more posted parameters.

Comment: if the variable not posted, it is equal  NULL or not set in sql?

Comment: Directly constructing the SQL query from user input creates SQL injection security issues. Don't do that, ever. Edit your code using prepared statements.

Comment: am using my custom function `runQuery`:

`public function runQuery($sql)
{
$stmt=$this->db->prepare($sql);
return $stmt;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try to proper forming `WHERE` statement. You should add conditions for `productTitle`, `category`, `manufacturer` fields only then `isset` proper `POST` fields.

Try this code:

```
<?php

if (
    isset($_POST["productName"]) || isset($_POST["searchCategory"]) ||
    isset($_POST["searchManufacturer"]) || isset($_POST["costFrom"]) ||
    isset($_POST["costTo"])
){
    $conditions = array();
    if (isset($_POST['productName'])) {
        $conditions[] = "(productTitle='".$_POST['productName']."')";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $conditions[] = "(category='".$_POST['searchCategory']."')";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['searchManufacturer'])) {
        $conditions[] = "(manufacturer='".$_POST['searchManufacturer']."')";
    }
    $where = implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    if ($where) {
        $where = 'WHERE '.$where;
    } else {
        $where = "";
    }

    $stmt=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM Products ". $where);
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: what are doing `$wheres` variable at the end?You assign `$wheres` to `$stmt`?

Comment: sorry, this was typo, I fix it

Comment: I think your solution is good, but i still have some issues 
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064`
at `$stmt->execute();` line :

`$stmt=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT* FROM Products ".$where);

}

$stmt->execute();`

Comment: change `$stmt=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT* FROM Products ".$where); } $stmt->execute();` to `$stmt=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM Products ".$where); } $stmt->execute();`

Comment: I've found some typos in `$conditions` (forgot about closing `'`). Try to run new fixed version of above code

Comment: Now there are no errors, but there are no results too..It outputs results only when i  use all criterias

Comment: Please add output of `echo "SELECT * FROM Products ". $where;` Let's see at our final select

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Products WHERE(productTitle='')AND(category='modulis')AND(manufacturer='')`
There are some products with this category, so I should get some results, but its blank.

Comment: Are you want to search by empty string? If no replace in coditions from `if (isset($_POST['productName'])) {` to `if (!empty($_POST['productName'])) {` and so on. Also check that `)AND(` should be `) AND (`

Comment: Please answer about empty POST string and I'll fix code into answer

Comment: I replaced and its working perfectly.Thanks.If you have some time could you  visit and see my another issue? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517555/jqueryautocomplete-values-and-categories-from-database